# Remove an entry from a docker-compose.yaml file based on user input

Tags: docker-compose, yaml, yq

I have a docker-compose.yaml file :

```
version: '3.3'
 
services:
   sqlserver:
    image: mysql:5
    environment:
      - DATA=1
    ports:
      - target: 3306
        published: 3306
 
   postgresql:
     image: postgresql:12
     environment:
      - DATA=1
     ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5432
```

As you can see there are two services: sqlserver and postgresql.

I am trying to generate a shell script (centos) that will remove entire entry of postgresql from this yaml file.

For example if user says remove postgresql then my yaml file will be:

```
version: '3.3'
 
services:
   sqlserver:
    image: mysql:5
    environment:
      - DATA=1
    ports:
      - target: 3306
        published: 3306
```

Comment: Can you install a YAML parser yq? - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

Comment: Yes , i can install that

Comment: Did the answer below help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Using a proper YAML parser like [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq). [Deleting by name](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/delete#delete-nested-entry-in-map) on a map is quite simple

```
yq e 'del(.services.postgresql)' yaml
```

Use the `-i` flag to do an in-place substitution, once you confirm the changes to be working as expected.

Or if you want the service to be deleted to be made configurable, pass it dynamically

```
v="postgresql" yq e '.services |= with_entries(select(.key != strenv(v)))' yaml
```